# Toggle button to switch between two fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, toggle

I have a swipe view app I am currently developing. On one of my swipe views, is it possible to have a list view in one fragment and when a toggle button is switched, switch to another fragment on the same swipe view that takes my list and dots the entries from the list view on a map as locations (preferably using Google maps API)? How would I do this?

Comment: Wouldn't you have problems with map scrolling and the swipe of the view? Did this implementation worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, just use a "if" conditional, but i dont know if is a good idea, maybe you can use another way.

You need to use a interface to send the information to another fragments.